# Entity Relations

Tags: database, entity-relationship

I've have some problems to set the relation between 2 kinds of tables.
I've a table called Patient (which holds some data about the patient ID, Address, Name..etc), and another table called Visits (which contains ID "this key is incremental variable and i don't insert it in the insertion qstmt", VisitDate, NextVisitDate, ..etc)

Now every patient may have more than one visit with different dates, and for each date we may have more than one patient, for e.g.:
date: 09-13-2012 may includes many patients
patient: visitdates : 09-13-2012, 09-09-2012, 07-03-2012

where should i put the foreign key..

*Note: although there is ID variable in for each visit and it an incremental var. but actually when i search in my program i search by Date, so, and correct me if i'm wrong could i make the Field Date "which it's type for sure is date, or should it be a composite key, or i can't consider the date as a key because it's not unique because many patients may have the same visitDate"*

Comment: should i create another table lets call it PatientsVisits which holds patientID, and VisitDate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me this looks like an ordinary one-to-many foreign key relationship. The table `Visits` has a foreign key `PatientId` to the patient who participates in the visit and the `VisitDate` is only an attribute in the `Visits` table and not part of the primary key. It hasn't a unique index either because on a given day there can be many visits, even the same patient may have two visits at the same day. If you want to forbid this, then you could create a composite unique key index on `PatientId` and `VisitDate`.

You can then create a SQL query on the `Visits` table by a specific `VisitDate` or date range and get all the visits at that date. With the `PatientId` foreign key of the visit you can join into the `Patients` table and get data about the patient of a visit.